# How get the content from a File-API object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file

How get the content from a File-API object in JavaScript?

I have a File-Api object and I want to retrieve all the file's content for sending it via POST in a Ajax Request.

Any suggest?

Comment: What is a File-API object and where did you get it from?

Comment: Did you look at the [examples there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) of file uploading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "File-API object" you mean a input of type `file` then you can use this:

```
// Multifile support
var files = getElementById('myfileinput').files

// Non multi support
var file = getElementById('myfileinput').value
```

Then you can get the file names with a loop:

```
var filenames = []
for (var i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; i++)
  filenames.push(files[i].name)
```